# What context should I pass to the AdapterItem from InformationFragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

**AdapterItem**

class AdapterItem(val context: Context, val userList: List): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterItem.ViewHolder>() {

```
class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
```

var numeLista: TextView
var caloriiLista: TextView

```
    init{
        numeLista=itemView.numeLista
        caloriiLista=itemView.caloriiLista
    }

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
   var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_items, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(itemView)

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.numeLista.text=userList[position].foodItems.get(0).foodName
    holder.caloriiLista.text=userList[position].foodItems.get(0).calories.toString()

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size
}
```

}

**InformationFragment:**

const val BASE_URL= "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/terrenjpeterson/caloriecounter/master/src/data/"

class InformationFragment : Fragment() {

```
private var binding: FragmentInformationBinding?   =null
private  val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

lateinit var adapterItem: AdapterItem
lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager



override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    recyclerview_lista.setHasFixedSize(true)
    linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
   recyclerview_lista.layoutManager=linearLayoutManager

    getMyData()




    val fragmentBinding = FragmentInformationBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    binding= fragmentBinding
    return fragmentBinding.root
}



override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding?.apply {
        viewModel= sharedViewModel
        informationFragment=this@InformationFragment
        lifecycleOwner= viewLifecycleOwner
    }

}
    private fun getMyData() {
    val retrofitBuilder= Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()
        .create(ApiInterface::class.java)

    val retrofitData= retrofitBuilder.getData()

    retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<List<MyDataItem>?> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>,
            response: Response<List<MyDataItem>?>
        ) {
            val responseBody= response.body()!!
            adapterItem= AdapterItem(,responseBody ) // ** here what context should I pass ???? ... I cant use baseContext**
            adapterItem.notifyDataSetChanged() 
            recyclerview_list.adapter=adapterItem



        }


        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>, t: Throwable) {
           Log.d( "informationFragment" , "onFailure: " + t.message)
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: you can pass requireContext() or context as an argument.

Comment: Every time I pass requireContext()or context to adapterItem my app keep crashing

Comment: I think here is also a problem: linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)... I should pass just "this" but I can use "this" only if I am in MainActivity and idk what to use when I am in a fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to pass the context as an arg you can use the context of the parent passed to your viewHolder

you shouldn't pass context. change:

```
class AdapterItem(val context: Context, val userList: List):
```

to:

```
class AdapterItem(val userList: List):
```

and

```
var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_items, parent, false)
```

to:

```
var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_items, parent, false)
```

Be careful if you want to pass context to the adapter, if you assigned the view context to a variable in your adapter, it probably would lead to a memory leak. Consider using WeakReference to avoid that if happens.

**Update**

move

```
recyclerview_lista.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

to onViewCreated

Comment: In the informationFragment, in getMyData function I should call AdapterItem wich has the first argument context

Comment: I've posted an answer with how my adapter and InformationFragment looks ... but my app still crashing

Comment: Post the log of the error you are getting.

Comment: 2022-07-24 00:30:51.398 5324-5324/com.example.dieta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dieta, PID: 5324
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dieta.InformationFragment.onCreateView(InformationFragment.kt:40)

Comment: check the answer again

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dieta.InformationFragment.onCreateView(InformationFragment.kt:42)

Comment: Sould I move linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context) and recyclerview_lista.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager also to onViewCreated or just linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context) ?

Comment: you'd better move

Answer (score 1):

**At first I tried to pass the data to a TextView and it worked without any problems... but now I wanna pass the data to a recycleview to be able to add a checkbox for each element**

**This is the code where I pass the data to TextView:**

const val BASE_URL= "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/terrenjpeterson/caloriecounter/master/src/data/"

class InformationFragment : Fragment() {

```
private var binding: FragmentInformationBinding?   =null
private  val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()





override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    getMyData()



    val fragmentBinding = FragmentInformationBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    binding= fragmentBinding
    return fragmentBinding.root
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding?.apply {
        viewModel= sharedViewModel
        informationFragment=this@InformationFragment
        lifecycleOwner= viewLifecycleOwner
    }
}
    private fun getMyData() {
    val retrofitBuilder= Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()
        .create(ApiInterface::class.java)

    val retrofitData= retrofitBuilder.getData()

    retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<List<MyDataItem>?> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>, response: Response<List<MyDataItem>?>) {
            val responseBody= response.body()!!

            val myStringBuilder = StringBuilder()
            for(myData in responseBody)
            {
                myStringBuilder.append(myData.foodItems.get(0).foodName)
                myStringBuilder.append(" ")
                myStringBuilder.append(myData.foodItems.get(0).calories)
                myStringBuilder.append("\n")
                myStringBuilder.append("\n")
            }

            txtId.text = myStringBuilder
        }


        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>, t: Throwable) {
           Log.d( "informationFragment" , "onFailure: " + t.message)
        }
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context of view parameter of your viewholder.

Answer (score 0):

**My app still keep crashing when it reaches the InformationFragment**

class AdapterItem( val userList: List): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterItem.ViewHolder>() {

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    var numeLista: TextView
    var caloriiLista: TextView
    init{
        numeLista=itemView.numeLista
        caloriiLista=itemView.caloriiLista
    }

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_items, parent, false)

    return ViewHolder(itemView)

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.numeLista.text=userList[position].foodItems.get(0).foodName
    holder.caloriiLista.text=userList[position].foodItems.get(0).calories.toString()

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size
}
```

}

const val BASE_URL= "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/terrenjpeterson/caloriecounter/master/src/data/"

class InformationFragment : Fragment() {

```
private var binding: FragmentInformationBinding? = null
private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

lateinit var adapterItem: AdapterItem
lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    recyclerview_lista.setHasFixedSize(true)
    linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    recyclerview_lista.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

    getMyData()


    val fragmentBinding = FragmentInformationBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    binding = fragmentBinding
    return fragmentBinding.root
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding?.apply {
        viewModel = sharedViewModel
        informationFragment = this@InformationFragment
        lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    }

}

private fun getMyData() {
    val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()
        .create(ApiInterface::class.java)

    val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getData()

    retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<List<MyDataItem>?> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>,
            response: Response<List<MyDataItem>?>
        ) {
            val responseBody = response.body()!!
            adapterItem = AdapterItem(responseBody)
            adapterItem.notifyDataSetChanged()
            recyclerview_lista.adapter=adapterItem
        }


        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>, t: Throwable) {
             d("informationFragment", "onFailure: " + t.message)
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: This is not an answer the question.